# how to use unicode in xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, unicode

please tell me how to use language like "HINDI" in xml.

my current xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<costs>
  <cost>text in hindi</cost>
</costs>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a character encoding (UTF-8 is the default for XML) that includes the characters you wish to use (UTF-8 covers pretty much everything, including everything you need for Hindi).

Then just use it.

You may need to configure your editor to save source files in UTF-8, but beyond that everything should Just Work.

Comment: i am already using UTF-8 but even though its not working. what about configuring editor? i am using visual studio 2008

Comment: No idea. I've never touched VS. http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=set%20visual%20studio%20to%20save%20in%20utf-8&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: And "doesn't work" is a useless description of a problem. Always describe "what you do", "what result you expect" and "what result you get".